# Compare two matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Say, I have two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$, what is a good way to check how *similar* they are...

There have been questions asked before, and the answer suggest *Froberius norm*, [for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507742/distance-similarity-between-two-matrices). But Frobenium norm only gives you 1 number, and hence fails to say which part of the matrices are closed and which are not.

This suggests the use of comparing the matrices singular values/eigenvalues. The drawback is then you can't tell anything about singular vectors/eigenvectors.

So would a good comparision be 1) Frobenius norm 2) Singular/Eigen Values and (3) Singular/Eigenvectors? Would that be a little bit too much?

Comment: "Similar" has a special meaning for matrices. Better find a different word to use.

Comment: "close-ness"...?

Comment: In what way are you looking for them to be similar? By this I mean is it the values in the matrices you are interested in or their behavior as linear transforms?