# Find matrix with same singular values (SVD)

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

Suppose that I have a matrix with only $0$ and $1$ cells,

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 &1 \\ 
 1& 1 &1 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1\\ 
 1& 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

and denote each Singular Value Decomposition as

$$H = U\Sigma V^{T}$$

where $U,V$ are unitary matrices and $\Sigma$ stores the singular values.

Is it possible to find another matrix $H^{'}$, of the same dimensions as $H$ again with only $0$ and $1$, that has the same singular value matrix $\Sigma$, i.e. $H^{'} = U^{'}\Sigma V^{'{T}}$???

If we didn't had the restriction that the cells of $H^{'}$ have to be either $0$ or $1$ we could simply find two unitary matrices $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{2}$ and calculate
$$H^{'}=Q_{1}HQ_{2},$$

where this matrix will have as SVD, $H^{'}=(Q_{1}U)\Sigma (V^{T}Q_{2})$, so it will have the same singular values.

However, I cannot find such matrices that obey the restriction that the elements of $H^{'}$ have to be $0$ or $1$.

---

The only case that I found is the following,

$H^{'}= I_{6\times 6} \times H \times I_{3\times 3}$

where $I$ are identity matrices. But is this the only way?? Because in that case $H^{'}$ will be equal to $H$ or with the rows of $H$ switched.

Comment: You could permute the rows and/or columns.

Comment: An example that is not obtained by permuting rows and columns is $$\pmatrix{0& 1& 1\cr 1 & 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 0 \cr1 & 1 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Indeed that is a case, and how did you manage to find it?? By trial and error or there is a systematic way??

Comment: Brute force search.